# Unity 3d jump player

Tags: unity-game-engine

Hi guys i have a problem with that code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnitySampleAssets.CrossPlatformInput;

namespace CompleteProject
{
    public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public float speed = 6f;            // The speed that the player will move at.


        Vector3 movement;                   // The vector to store the direction of the player's movement.
        Animator anim;                      // Reference to the animator component.
        Rigidbody playerRigidbody;          // Reference to the player's rigidbody.
#if !MOBILE_INPUT
        int floorMask;                      // A layer mask so that a ray can be cast just at gameobjects on the floor layer.
        float camRayLength = 100f;          // The length of the ray from the camera into the scene.
#endif

        void Awake ()
        {
#if !MOBILE_INPUT
            // Create a layer mask for the floor layer.
            floorMask = LayerMask.GetMask ("Floor");
#endif

            // Set up references.
            anim = GetComponent <Animator> ();
            playerRigidbody = GetComponent <Rigidbody> ();
        }


        void FixedUpdate ()
        {
            // Store the input axes.
            float h = CrossPlatformInputManager.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
            float v = CrossPlatformInputManager.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");

            // Move the player around the scene.
            Move (h, v);

            // Turn the player to face the mouse cursor.
            Turning ();

            // Animate the player.
            Animating (h, v);
        }


        void Move (float h, float v)
        {
            // Set the movement vector based on the axis input.
            movement.Set (h, 0f, v);

            // Normalise the movement vector and make it proportional to the speed per second.
            movement = movement.normalized * speed * Time.deltaTime;

            // Move the player to it's current position plus the movement.
            playerRigidbody.MovePosition (transform.position + movement);
        }


        void Turning ()
        {
#if !MOBILE_INPUT
            // Create a ray from the mouse cursor on screen in the direction of the camera.
            Ray camRay = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay (Input.mousePosition);

            // Create a RaycastHit variable to store information about what was hit by the ray.
            RaycastHit floorHit;

            // Perform the raycast and if it hits something on the floor layer...
            if(Physics.Raycast (camRay, out floorHit, camRayLength, floorMask))
            {
                // Create a vector from the player to the point on the floor the raycast from the mouse hit.
                Vector3 playerToMouse = floorHit.point - transform.position;

                // Ensure the vector is entirely along the floor plane.
                playerToMouse.y = 0f;

                // Create a quaternion (rotation) based on looking down the vector from the player to the mouse.
                Quaternion newRotatation = Quaternion.LookRotation (playerToMouse);

                // Set the player's rotation to this new rotation.
                playerRigidbody.MoveRotation (newRotatation);
            }
#else

            Vector3 turnDir = new Vector3(CrossPlatformInputManager.GetAxisRaw("Mouse X") , 0f , CrossPlatformInputManager.GetAxisRaw("Mouse Y"));

            if (turnDir != Vector3.zero)
            {
                // Create a vector from the player to the point on the floor the raycast from the mouse hit.
                Vector3 playerToMouse = (transform.position + turnDir) - transform.position;

                // Ensure the vector is entirely along the floor plane.
                playerToMouse.y = 0f;

                // Create a quaternion (rotation) based on looking down the vector from the player to the mouse.
                Quaternion newRotatation = Quaternion.LookRotation(playerToMouse);

                // Set the player's rotation to this new rotation.
                playerRigidbody.MoveRotation(newRotatation);
            }
#endif
        }


        void Animating (float h, float v)
        {
            // Create a boolean that is true if either of the input axes is non-zero.
            bool walking = h != 0f || v != 0f;

            // Tell the animator whether or not the player is walking.
            anim.SetBool ("IsWalking", walking);
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried many ways , but unfortunately none of them works , I need that my player can jump , and maybe even do a double jump . I just can not figure out how to blow it up .
I say thanks to those who will help me.

Comment: I think will need more background. Is this a top down view 3d game? Do the controls move the player along the X and Y axis, and you want the character to jump on the Z axis?

Comment: Yes man, is not a very 3d game, but the view is in 3d. I need the player qhen i press the space jump on the Z axis, can u help me to do this? @user2215331

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use RigidBody's AddForce function: http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddForce.html

As in the example, use a Vector3.Up multiplied by the force of your jump.

You can include this code in the FidexUpdate function. If the jump key is down (http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetKeyDown.html), then AddForce to the player.

Comment: yes but where i can add the code? You can help me? Thanks

Comment: I have see now tha player move only on the x axis and z, if for example write at y 10, the player is in the air. Bui i need do it i press jump the y axis

Comment: I have try the code, but with vector3.up the player don't do anything. I have try to write Rigidbody.AddForce(Vector3.up * 10); and playerRigidbody.AddForce(Vector3.up * 10); but don't work again, but when i press the space button the if work correct because print "space key was pressed". @user2215331

Comment: You are overwriting the vertical speed in this line:  movement.Set (h, 0f, v). Instead of using 0f, use rigidbody.velocity.y ,that way you won't change the vertical component of the rigidbody's speed.

Comment: And with that way i can change it? You have skype? Could you give me a little hand ? Thank you, this jump is driving me crazy , just can not. If u want send the name in private message.. @user2215331