# Timer unity3d col.gameObject.name

Tags: c#, timer, unity-game-engine

I try to create a timer can it start when the player destroy the object. 
I need, when the player destroy the object call "test", start a timer and for 10 seconds the player speed is change, from 5f to 10f. When the timer is 10 or more i need the player speed come back to 5f.

This is my code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnitySampleAssets.CrossPlatformInput;

namespace CompleteProject
{
    public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public static float speed = 5f;  
        public float timer = 5.0f;
        float timerMin = 1.0f;

        Vector3 movement;                   // The vector to store the direction of the player's movement.
        Animator anim;                      // Reference to the animator component.
        Rigidbody playerRigidbody;          // Reference to the player's rigidbody.
        #if !MOBILE_INPUT
        int floorMask;                      // A layer mask so that a ray can be cast just at gameobjects on the floor layer.
        float camRayLength = 100f;          // The length of the ray from the camera into the scene.
        #endif




        void Awake ()
        {
            #if !MOBILE_INPUT
            // Create a layer mask for the floor layer.
            floorMask = LayerMask.GetMask ("Floor");
            #endif

            // Set up references.
            anim = GetComponent <Animator> ();
            playerRigidbody = GetComponent <Rigidbody> ();

        }



        void FixedUpdate ()
        {

            timer += Time.deltaTime;
            // Store the input axes.
            float h = CrossPlatformInputManager.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
            float v = CrossPlatformInputManager.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");

            // Move the player around the scene.
            Move (h, v);

            // Turn the player to face the mouse cursor.
            Turning ();

            // Animate the player.
            Animating (h, v);

        }


        void Move (float h, float v)
        {
            // Set the movement vector based on the axis input.
            movement.Set (h, 0f, v);

            // Normalise the movement vector and make it proportional to the speed per second.
            movement = movement.normalized * speed * Time.deltaTime;

            // Move the player to it's current position plus the movement.
            playerRigidbody.MovePosition (transform.position + movement);


        }



        void Update () 
        { 
            if(Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Space))
            { 

            } 
        }




        void OnCollisionEnter (Collision col)
        {


            if(col.gameObject.name == "coin10")
            {
                Destroy(col.gameObject);
                CoinManager.coin=CoinManager.coin+10;

            }
            if(col.gameObject.name == "coin5")
            {
                Destroy(col.gameObject);
                CoinManager.coin=CoinManager.coin+5;

            }
            if(col.gameObject.name == "coin1")
            {
                Destroy(col.gameObject);
                CoinManager.coin=CoinManager.coin+1;

            }
            if(col.gameObject.name == "eterium1")
            {
                Destroy(col.gameObject);
                EteriumManager.eterium=EteriumManager.eterium+1;

            }
            if(col.gameObject.name == "test")
            {

            }

        }

        void Turning ()
        {
            #if !MOBILE_INPUT
            // Create a ray from the mouse cursor on screen in the direction of the camera.
            Ray camRay = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay (Input.mousePosition);

            // Create a RaycastHit variable to store information about what was hit by the ray.
            RaycastHit floorHit;

            // Perform the raycast and if it hits something on the floor layer...
            if(Physics.Raycast (camRay, out floorHit, camRayLength, floorMask))
            {
                // Create a vector from the player to the point on the floor the raycast from the mouse hit.
                Vector3 playerToMouse = floorHit.point - transform.position;

                // Ensure the vector is entirely along the floor plane.
                playerToMouse.y = 0f;

                // Create a quaternion (rotation) based on looking down the vector from the player to the mouse.
                Quaternion newRotatation = Quaternion.LookRotation (playerToMouse);

                // Set the player's rotation to this new rotation.
                playerRigidbody.MoveRotation (newRotatation);
            }
            #else

            Vector3 turnDir = new Vector3(CrossPlatformInputManager.GetAxisRaw("Mouse X") , 0f , CrossPlatformInputManager.GetAxisRaw("Mouse Y"));

            if (turnDir != Vector3.zero)
            {
                // Create a vector from the player to the point on the floor the raycast from the mouse hit.
                Vector3 playerToMouse = (transform.position + turnDir) - transform.position;

                // Ensure the vector is entirely along the floor plane.
                playerToMouse.y = 0f;

                // Create a quaternion (rotation) based on looking down the vector from the player to the mouse.
                Quaternion newRotatation = Quaternion.LookRotation(playerToMouse);

                // Set the player's rotation to this new rotation.
                playerRigidbody.MoveRotation(newRotatation);
            }
            #endif
        }


        void Animating (float h, float v)
        {
            // Create a boolean that is true if either of the input axes is non-zero.
            bool walking = h != 0f || v != 0f;

            // Tell the animator whether or not the player is walking.
            anim.SetBool ("IsWalking", walking);
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the part where i need the timer start:

```
if(col.gameObject.name == "test")
        {

        }
```

I have try with timer -= time.deltatime but time.deltatime is not a timer. The value of the timer is the value of the object destroy.
Everyone can help me to do this timer?

Example:

```
if(timer<=10){
speed=10f;
}
else
{
speed=5f;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a [**Coroutine**](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Coroutine.html).

1. Start the Coroutine.
2. Change the player_speed.
3. Wait your time.
4. Reset the speed.

---

```
if(col.gameObject.name == "test")
{
    StartCoroutine("SlowSpeed");
}

private IEnumerator SlowSpeed()
{
    player_speed = 10;

    yield return new WaitForSeconds(10f);

    player_speed = 5;
}
```

Comment: Yeah but when i write: Private IEnumerator etc i give this error: "the name  IEnumerator does not exist in the current contest"

Comment: @Andreaphp write it as it is above and it will work. You should also try reading the link on Coroutines, so you get a better understanding.

Comment: Awesome, it work! Thank u so much man! Man there is a little problem. I need the run the slowspeed() when the player have destroy the object ( in the if "if(col.gameObject.name == "test")"). How i can do that? Now when i start the game the player speed for 10 seconds is 10f and after come back to 5f. I need the player speed come to 10f when the player have destroy the object. Thanks again man!
@FunctionR

Comment: I edited my post above so that you know where that goes. Good luck!

Comment: i do it :D. If u want please help me with this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28453239/unity-3d-jump-player Thanks again!